# Unable to pull info from arraylist to jpanel

Tags: jpanel

im not able to compilate my code to show some custom info from an ArrayList into a Jpanel. Seems like the problema is on the line 109, ive checked multiple pages and im still not able to come up with the answer.
please help!

The main situation is that i get info from the database and i store it into an ArrayList> then i proceed to decompose that array to get the values from the database and adding those into a ArrayList to expose the info more clear

```
package FP.Graphics;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import FP.Domain.ListamientoDeudas;
import FP.Domain.MySQL;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;

public class EstadoCuotas extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static String Identificador;
    public String Item1;//contenedor del nombre a listar
    public String Item2; //contenedor del mes a listar
    public String Item3;//contenedor del monto a listar
    ArrayList<ListamientoDeudas> source;//contenedor de instancias de la clase "Listamiento"
    private JTable table1;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EstadoCuotas frame = new EstadoCuotas(Identificador);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Create the frame.

     */
    public EstadoCuotas(String identificadorFromMainWindow) {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        Identificador=identificadorFromMainWindow;

        JButton btnVolver = new JButton("Volver");
        btnVolver.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MenuPrincipal menu =new MenuPrincipal(Identificador);
                menu.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnVolver.setBounds(348, 527, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnVolver);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(69, 32, 672, 452);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);







        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aux = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();//Lista de listas de string auxiliar para obtener las deudas del socio o socios
        if (Identificador == "1" || Identificador== "2")//Si el nivel de autoridad es "ADMIN" o "GESTOR" se va a poder ver toda la informacion
        {
            aux = MySQL.GetAllDebtDataPart1();//Igualamos la lista auxiliar a la lista que retorna la funcion "GetAllDebtData" (la cual trae todas las deudas activas en el sistema)      
        }
        else //De lo contrario se mostrara la informacion del socio que consulta
        {
            aux = MySQL.GetSingleDebtDataPart1(Identificador);//Igualamos la lista auxiliar a la lista que retorna la funcion "GetAllDebtData" (la cual trae todas las deudas activas en el sistema para el socio afectado)
        }
        source = new ArrayList<ListamientoDeudas>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < aux.size() ; i++) 
        {
            ArrayList<String> currentList = aux.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < currentList.size(); j++)
            {
              ListamientoDeudas deuda=new ListamientoDeudas(currentList.get(0).toString(),currentList.get(1).toString(),currentList.get(2).toString());
              source.add(deuda);
            }
        }  
        String[] columnNames = {"Nombre","Monto","Mes"};
        Object[] data = source.toArray();
        table1 = new JTable(columnNames,data);
        table1.setBounds(69, 32, 672, 452);
        contentPane.add(table1);

    }
}
```

in adition here it is the class ListamientoDeudas

```
package FP.Domain;

public class ListamientoDeudas {
    public ListamientoDeudas(String item1, String item2, String item3)//Constructor que recibe 3 parametros
    {
        this.name = item1;//igualacion de variable "item1" a la variable "name"
        this.month = item2;//igualacion de variable "item2" a la variable "month"
        this.amount = item3;//igualacion de variable "item3" a la variable "amount"
    }

    public String name ;//variable String
    public String month ;//variable String
    public String amount ;//variable String
}
```

******UPDATE*******
this update is to show how does the function MySQL.GetAllDebtDataPart1() and MySQL.GetSingleDebtDataPart1(Identificador) Works, these basically brings values from the DB when they have debt. the funtions itself returns an ArrayList>, one of the possibilities as read on the answer from @Abra was to return a variable of the type object[][], is there a way to achieve that trying to implement the same query on the MySQL functions?

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> GetAllDebtDataPart1()
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aux = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString);
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM ProyectoJuan.Transacciones where Pago='No'");
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            ArrayList<String> aux2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            aux2 = GetAllDebtDataPart2(resultSet.getString("ReferenciaSocio"), resultSet.getString("Mes"), resultSet.getString("Monto"));
            aux.add(aux2);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }


    Close();
    return aux;
}

public static ArrayList<String> GetAllDebtDataPart2(String identificador, String item1, String item2)
{
    ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect2 = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString);
        statement2 = connect2.createStatement();
        resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery("Select * From ProyectoJuan.Socios Where Id=" + identificador);

        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            container.add(resultSet.getString("Nombre"));
            container.add(item1);
            container.add(item2);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }


    return container;
}
```

---

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> GetSingleDebtDataPart1(String identificador)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aux = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString);
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM ProyectoJuan.Transacciones where Pago='No'");
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            ArrayList<String> aux2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            aux2 = GetSingleDebtDataPart2(identificador, resultSet.getString("ReferenciaSocio"), resultSet.getString("Mes"), resultSet.getString("Monto"));
            if (aux2.size() != 0)
            {
                aux.add(aux2);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }


    Close();
    return aux;
}

public static ArrayList<String> GetSingleDebtDataPart2(String cedula, String idSocio, String mes, String monto)
{
    ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect2 = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString);
        statement2 = connect2.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM ProyectoJuan.Socios where Cedula=" + cedula);
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            if (idSocio == resultSet.getString("Id"))
            {
                container.add(resultSet.getString("Nombre"));
                container.add(mes);
                container.add(monto);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


    return container;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual compiler error message and without knowing which line of your code is line 109, I can only guess, but from the code you posted, the call to `javax.swing.JTable` constructor is wrong. I think you want this constructor: `JTable(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)`.

Comment: @Abra Yes indeed thats what its wrong, but how can i achieve to make the constructor like that when i have those values? i was trying to think something like .ItemSource property from XAML but it doesnt exist on java/swing, can you help me to reach a valid constructor within these variables?

Comment: From your code, it looks like class `MySQL` is one that you wrote. If so, I would change method `GetAllDebtDataPart1()` to return `Object[][]` instead of `ArrayList`. Similarly for method `GetSingleDebtDataPart1()`.

Comment: @Abra ive performed an update, would you mind to check it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor of class `EstadoCuotas`, change type of variable `source` and populate as follows:

```
int rows = aux.size();
int columns = 0;
if (rows > 0) {
    ArrayList<String> primero = aux.get(0);
    if (primero != null) {
        columns = primero.size();
    }
}
Object[][] source = new Object[rows][columns];
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    ArrayList<String> aRow = aux.get(row);
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
        source[row][col] = aRow.get(col);
    }
}
```

Then you can create `table1` as follows

```
table1 = new JTable(source, columnNames);
```